# A special character I am trying to include in a page keeps getting rejected with error "Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response."

Tags: json, characters

I'm working on a site that contains passages in old spellings of the Luxembourgish language. This means that it contains an extreme assortment of weird diacritics, strangely placed apostrophes and mixtures of characters, in order to create the various "Umlauts" that the language contains. (Our  grammar and orthography were standardized very late.)

My problem is that for some reason the letter **û** (u circumflex) is not accepted and throws an error however I enter it. I have tried to insert it in the Gutenberg editor, the WPBakery editor, even in HTML, both literally and as a HTML code (both `&ucirc;` and `&#94; u` don't work), but nothing works.

I always get a message that says: `Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response.`

In case it's important or the prior characters affect it in a weird way, the whole sentence is:

> Éch hun dir ěwég Trei geschw**û**or.

In the above sentence, there are a multitude of weird characters, but only the û makes wordpress scream and throw a tantrum. Why?

Does Wordpress use this character as a placeholder for something? Or is it the server the site is hosted on? I've tried every way I know to insert that letter into the text and I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is the JSON request it sends out and the response it gets to this request.

```json
{"id":[[an id number]],"content":"<!-- wp:separator -->\n<hr class=\"wp-block-separator\"/>\n<!-- /wp:separator -->\n\n<!-- wp:heading {\"textAlign\":\"center\",\"level\":3} -->\n<h3 class=\"has-text-align-center\"><em>Onst Heemechtsland</em></h3>\n<!-- /wp:heading -->\n\n<!-- wp:separator -->\n<hr class=\"wp-block-separator\"/>\n<!-- /wp:separator -->\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph {\"style\":{\"color\":{\"text\":\"#808000\"}}} -->\n<p class=\"has-text-color\" style=\"color:#808000\"><em><strong>Werkinformationen:</strong></em></p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px;\"><strong>Titel: </strong>Onst Heemechtsland</p>\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px;\"><strong>Komponist:  </strong>Laurent Menager</p>\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px;\"><strong>Text:</strong> Jean Nicolas Moes</p>\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px;\"><strong>Datum: </strong>Unbekannt</p>\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px;\"><strong>Besetzung: </strong>TTBB a cappella</p>\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px;\"><strong>Einordnung:</strong> weltliches Vokalwerk, Chorlied TTBB a cappella</p>\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px;\"><strong>Textincipit:</strong> ,,Éch hun dir ěwég Trei geschwûor\"</p>\n\n<!-- wp:paragraph {\"style\":{\"color\":{\"text\":\"#808000\"}}} -->\n<p class=\"has-text-color\" style=\"color:#808000\"><strong><em>Materialbeschreibung:</em></strong></p>\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\n\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px\"><strong>Typ: </strong>Edition: Partitur, Verlag Decker-Müllendorff, Luxembourg</p>\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px\"><strong>Quellenart &amp; Umfang:</strong>&nbsp; Partitur, 10 S.</p>\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px\"><strong>Format: </strong>17,2 x 27,2 cm</p>\n<p style=\"padding-left: 40px\"><strong>Signatur:</strong> Archiv des Sang &amp; Klang, O2</p>"}
```

```html
<html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: [[a long id number]]<br><br><a href='javascript:history.back();'>[Go Back]</a></body></html>
```

Comment: That character does not have a special placeholder or significance, have you updated to the latest version of WordPress?

Comment: I'm currently on 5.7.5, but I can't change this, as I'm only responsible for a small part of the site and there are several plugins that I don't know that might be affected by an update.

Comment: updating to 5.8.x or 5.9.x will update the editor and JS dependencies as well as REST API code, it may have a direct impact on this. Plugins can be eliminated as a cause by deactivating them and retesting. My own site is on the latest version and has no issues saving a test post with the words `Éch hun dir ěwég Trei geschwûor.`. You may want to look at the response from the server, if it's not valid JSON, what is it? You'll likely find the cause by doing that

Comment: I will check with the admin of the site if it would be possible to update to the latest version then and about testing the plugins. I am not currently at a computer I can edit the site from, but I will edit my question to feature the JSON response I'm getting as soon as possible. Thanks already for the help!

Comment: I have added the request and response I get. Is that what you meant, or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: the response contains the expected JSON, but there's a HTML tag and a HTML page appended which mentions support IDs that should not be there. This is why you are having issues, it's unlikely the character is related to the issue. REST APIs return JSON, they can't return JSON + random output

Comment: I think I was unclear: The first line is the request sent out by the page, and the second line (the html thing) is the response.

Comment: ok then this is either a hosting issue or there is a PHP fatal error, you should not be seeing raw HTML tags, you should be seeing JSON. Even if the REST API encountered an error, it would JSON encode that error, never as raw HTML

Comment: Then I assume that it's probably a hosting issue. It's a university site and our network settings are all over the place to say the least. I will try updating the site and looking at the plugins when I get the ok, but for now, thank you for your help :)